# How to avoid iOS app being terminated by system too often when in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory

I'm building an iOS app for iOS 8 & 9 and I am facing the problem that when the app goes to background the system is terminating it after just 2 or 3 minutes.

My testing is easy:

1. I kill all running apps from my iPhone.
2. I restart my iPhone (to ensure no other apps are taking memory).
3. I launch my app.
4. I do nothing inside my app.
5. I press the "Home" button, moving my app to background.
6. I wait doing nothing else for 2 or 3 minutes.
7. I open my app again and surprise, the system has terminated it and now it is restarting as a new launch.

Some comments:

- The app does not use CoreLocation in background neither any other service.
- I've profiled the app, trying to understand if it is consuming too much memory. When moving to background, it consumes around 25Mb of RAM memory. I'm attaching a screenshot below.
- This behavior has been tested on iPhone 5, 5s, 6, 6+.
- In iPhone 6s and 6s+ seems to take a bit more time to happen, but still happens.

[image: App Allocations Profile]

My question is: Do you know why would this be happening? anything I might not be considering or just forgetting?

I don't want to force my app to run in background by using CoreLocation or something similar. And I'm ok if the system kills my app eventually. What I don't want is that everytime I move my app to background the system terminates it.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: in app delegate add break point in methods and see it is calling `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` again

Comment: What is your app actually doing? e.g. OpenGL calls will get your app killed.

Answer (score 0):

All applications are automatically killed by the system

According the Apple documentation:

> App Termination
>
> Apps must be prepared for termination to happen at any time and should not >wait to save user data or perform other critical tasks. System-initiated >termination is a normal part of an app’s life cycle. The system usually >terminates apps so that it can reclaim memory and make room for other apps >being launched by the user, but the system may also terminate apps that >are misbehaving or not responding to events in a timely manner.
>
> Suspended apps receive no notification when they are terminated; the >system kills the process and reclaims the corresponding memory. If an app >is currently running in the background and not suspended, the system calls >the applicationWillTerminate: of its app delegate prior to termination. >The system does not call this method when the device reboots.
>
> In addition to the system terminating your app, the user can terminate >your app explicitly using the multitasking UI. User-initiated termination >has the same effect as terminating a suspended app. The app’s process is >killed and no notification is sent to the app.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1

You can track position but you will certainly see a blue status bar to indicate that an application use GPS tracking.

Maybe you can try to "wake up" your app in background with silent notification...

If it is not necessary to keep your app alive, trust the system...

Comment: Thanks for the message. I was mostly aware of this already. My question here is why is terminating it so fast? and if there is something I can do to avoid this. When playing with other apps, I see that some take more time to get terminated by the system.

Comment: @vilanovi you can check it  NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);

Comment: in applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't need my app running in the background. I just don't want the system "kills" my app that fast. The app can be paused in the background.

Comment: Nothing you can do. Add the code to save state when you go to the background, and restore the state when you are launched. It _will_ happen when the user runs loads of apps.

Comment: @gnasher729 understood: nothing I can do about it unless trying to restore the state of the app. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1. Some error in inside your code. Please select debug Navigator before run your app... Now you can able to find your error..
2. Or too much memory also it will terminated..

Comment: I am already aware of such problems. Here I'm asking about a more general understanding of how iOS manages background apps.

Answer (score -2):

Apps which are running in the background *drain battery life faster*, It gives you a bad perception of the device, instead of the app, because the average consumer has no idea that it's an app draining battery. 
Thus iOS won't allow your app to run in the background, more than a few seconds. But there are some exception, **an app can request extension to this by declaring that its starting a Background Task.**

for more info you can check below links:
http://blog.dkaminsky.info/2013/01/27/keep-your-ios-app-running-in-background-forever/

http://www.speirs.org/blog/2012/1/2/misconceptions-about-ios-multitasking.html

Comment: I'm not asking about background app execution. Please, read the question before answering it.

Comment: dear vilanovi, for atlandu's answer you commented that why app terminating so fast? For that question straight answer is to save battery life. For your second query that is how to avoid this?, For that i recommended to use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler by providing links.

Comment: Yes, true. But the nature of the question is no to understand how to make the app perform in background but intstead try to understand why and when is being killed by the system.